# Microsoft Load Test: Most of the test are failing because Agent machines not responding

Tags: performance-testing, msloadtest

I have following infrastructure:

1 Test Controller Machine
2 Test Agent Machines

Most of the test are failing because agents are not responding in timely fashion.

All the configurations are correct.

Comment: Use better agents and controllers or a faster network or have less non-test traffic on the network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used separate NIC for individual VM.

Also the windows updates were downloaded parallel which caused the bandwidth consumption.

Used SSClient.exe to update system manually. 
Solved my problem....

Thanks for the suggestion.